# Using 'this' inside anonymous, IDE: potentially invalid usage

Tags: javascript

Is the next function (which actually works) bad in term of best practices?

The IDE is warning me about

> 'Potentially invalid usage of 'this'.
>   Checks for Javascript 'this' to be in the same closure or outer
>   content.

```
$(document).on('change', '#select-all', function(){
    if( this.checked ) {
      $(this).closest('table').find('input[name="row-id"]').each( function() {
        this.checked = true; // Here
      })
    }
    else {
      $(this).closest('table').find('input[name="row-id"]').each( function() {
        this.checked = false; // Here
      });
    }
  });
```

When I check a checkbox with ID `select-all`, it marks all the other as selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably it happens because your IDE doesn't know what object `this` refers to in the functions you use, hence giving you a hint that `this` might refer to `window` object or another context.

By the way, your code can be rewritten to:

```
$(document).on("change", "#select-all", function() {
    $(this)
      .closest("table")
      .find("input[name='row-id']")
      .prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, one question. In the `prop()`, `this.checked` refers to the `'#select-all'` `this`, or to `.find()` `this` ?

Comment: @Jorge Here `this` will refer to element with ID `select-all`.

Answer (score 3):

@Jorge it has to do with the scope of closures in javascript and the usage of `this`.

For further reading try this one: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

I haven't read it completely but it sums it pretty nicely.

Comment: link is dead as of Feb 2016